# Will Chrome allow my extension to send HTTPS requests to a self-signed server certificate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension

Hopefully my question has been pretty clear. I'm trying to get send AJAX (HTTPS) requests to a  server that I own from the background page of my Chrome extension. From what I've read, I can't send AJAX requests to an unsigned/self-signed server without tinkering with my own browser settings, but I was wondering if Chrome extensions have different privileges. (I also cannot afford to have all of my users change their browser settings to get my app to work for them.)

From what I've seen of my own extension, all of the HTTPS requests that my background page have sent have been 'canceled' (from viewing the dev console).

Is there a way around this, besides getting a signed cert or doing something hacky like emulating a secure connection with HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test this is to add a permissions section to your extensions manifest with the url of the server you are making the request too.  So it might look a little something like:

`{
   "name": "test",
   "version: "1",
   "permissions": [ "https://domainofselfsignedcert" ]
 }`

If this doesn't work, the next option is to look at the experimental settings API (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.settings.html) unfortunately this is not yet fully available, but might give you the ability to allow access to your domain without a cert.